# Python kmeans value error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to pass a pandas dataframe to the kmeans algorithm of the sklearn package. The dataframe has a date index with 52 dates (one per week) and the columns are different articles. The column values are the selling quantity of the corresponding week. For a better calculation I calculated the percentage change and that's how it looks like:

```
ARTICLE         47070868       489070875       29470899       99070943       \
DATE                                                                     
2017-01-02       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000       0.000000   
2017-01-09      -0.015625      -0.074928      -0.083333       0.230769   
2017-01-16       0.232804       0.007788       0.284091       0.062500   
2017-01-23       0.051502       0.174652       0.011799       0.117647   
2017-01-30       0.200000      -0.082895       0.008746       0.807018   
2017-02-06       0.057823       0.040172      -0.020231      -0.411003   
2017-02-13       0.000000      -0.037241      -0.014749      -0.087912   
2017-02-20       0.125402       0.259312       0.218563       0.138554   
2017-02-27      -0.265714      -0.271900      -0.233415      -0.343915   
2017-03-06       0.470817       0.293750       0.448718       0.661290   
2017-03-13       0.002646       0.013285      -0.057522      -0.048544
```

The dataframe has 52 rows and 8753 columns. if i pass the dataframe to the kmeans algorithm I get the following error:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (52,) and (8753,)

Here is the code:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(data_pct_change)
print(kmeans.labels_)
np.savetxt('log_sebastian2017.txt', kmeans.labels_, newline="\n")
for i, cluster_center in enumerate(kmeans.cluster_centers_):
        plp.plot(data_pct_change.index, cluster_center, label='Center {0}'.format(i))
plp.legend(loc='best')
plp.show()
```

The error is thrown in the loop when trying to plot.
If I do this code:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0).fit(data_pct_change)
print(kmeans.labels_)
np.savetxt('log_sebastian2017.txt', kmeans.labels_, newline="\n")
for i, cluster_center in enumerate(kmeans.cluster_centers_):
        plp.plot(cluster_center, label='Center {0}'.format(i))
plp.legend(loc='best')
plp.show()
```

it works fine, but the scale of the x- and y axis is incorrect, it reaches on x from 0 to about 8700 (probably 8753, the number of columns) and on y from 0 to 10000 (which is also wrong, the maximum percentage change in the dataframe is 17,6).

What am I doing wrong here? Also the amount of generated labels is wrong (in both cases the algorithm prints an array of length 52 for `kmean.labels_`, but should be 8573)

Can someone help me to do this clustering correctly? Is my dataframe the wrong way round for the kmeans?

Comment: Does `data_pct_change` has similar structure as the raw data you described above (52x8753 dataframe)? If not, how do you preprocess the data? If yes, are you trying to cluster weeks that has similar sales? That sounds a bit unusual. Anyway, consider providing complete code & dataset so others can replicate the issue & help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the data is described is a axcerpt of the data_pct_change